# Boost asio http deadline error?

Tags: c++, boost

The code bellow is mainly the HTTP client example with very few changes to support a download deadline.

It works as expected, but in rare cases e.g. if the internet is unstable, it doesn't work and the deadline can be more than what I set (20 or more seconds when I set 10). This happens very rarely and I am unable to reproduce this, it happens when I don't expect it.

To avoid posting a ton of lines (because few will read them) here is the place where I believe the error lies:

```
deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(deadline));

tcp::resolver::query query(server, "http");
resolver_.async_resolve(query,
boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
boost::asio::placeholders::error,
boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::check_deadline, this));
```

Is the order of those lines correct?

And here is the check deadline function:

```
void check_deadline()
{
    if(deadline_cancelled)
        return;
    else if (deadline_.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
        socket_.close();
    else
        deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::check_deadline, this));
}
```

Comment: What does `handle_resolve` do? Also, by 'the deadline can be more than what I set,' do you mean the timer callback doesn't fire in time, or it doesn't close the socket?

Comment: Not sure what happens but the program stucks endlessly waiting. I know it's this function but I don't know more as I can't reproduce the error. `handle_resolve` begins sending the request. The function is the same as the one boost provides in the http client example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `async_wait()` on the deadline timer too. If you don't, you won't get notified, you just check (after the fact) whether the time *had* expired.

Then if it completes (with an `ec` other than `operation_aborted`) then you should

- `cancel()` the async operations on the socket
- optionally close the socket

PS. Mmm. It /seems/ that you are doing something similar, although it's unclear where

- `deadline_cancelled` comes from
- why you don't accept the `error_code` in the completion handler for `deadline_.async_await` and
- why you are juggling with time comparisons manually, instead of trusting that the completion handler means what it says

**Update** Here's a full example doing a HTTP request. In fact, it downloads a million digits of PI from http://www.angio.net/pi/digits.html. This takes a while.

At the start of receiving the response I set a deadline timer for 800ms (and so the transfer should be - correctly - aborted).

This works as advertised. Pay special attention to the canceling of the socket and timer. Note that you could call `expires_from_now()` again after receiving each chunk of data. This is likely what you want. It **will** implicitly `cancel()` the timer each time it hadn't yet expired, so be prepared to handle the `operatorion_aborted` messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>

class client
{
    public:
        client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
            : deadline_(io_service),
            socket_(io_service)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter message: ";
            static char const raw[] = "GET /pi/digits/pi1000000.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.angio.net\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

            static_assert(sizeof(raw)<=sizeof(request_), "too large");

            size_t request_length = strlen(raw);
            std::copy(raw, raw+request_length, request_);

            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                    boost::asio::buffer(request_, request_length),
                    boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void deadline_expiration(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            return;

        std::cout << "\nDEADLINE REACHED\n";
        socket_.cancel();
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
            size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "starting read loop\n";

            deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(800));
            //deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(800));
            deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::deadline_expiration, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
                    //boost::asio::buffer(reply_, sizeof(reply_)),
                    reply_, '\n',
                    boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Reply: " << &reply_ << "\n";
            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
                    //boost::asio::buffer(reply_, sizeof(reply_)),
                    reply_, '\n',
                    boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
            deadline_.cancel(); // no need for after transfer completed
        }
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    char request_[1024];
    boost::asio::streambuf reply_;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("www.angio.net", "80");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        client c(io_service, iterator);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8218cc4a55cf3e2b) (Coliru doesn't support internet connectivity)