# boost::future and continuations - value set, but future still blocks

Tags: c++, boost, future, continuations

I am trying to make the following continuation work - but `f.get()` blocks. Whats wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

struct Foo {

   boost::future<int> start() {
      return p.get_future();
   }

   void finish() {
      p.set_value(23);
   }

   boost::promise<int> p;
};

int main () {

   Foo foo;

   foo.start().then([](boost::future<int> f) {
      std::cout << "done:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
   });

   foo.finish();
}
```

It'll print the `"done:"`, so the future fires, but it'll then just "hang" on `f.get()` .. I am lost.

To build:

```
clang++ -o test8 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lboost_thread -lboost_system \
  -I/home/oberstet/boost_1_55_0 -L/home/oberstet/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib \
  test8.cpp
```

**UPDATE**: The following code change will make the example work - but why? Since `f2` isn't used anyway. Puzzled again.

```
   boost::future<void> f2 = foo.start().then([](boost::future<int> f) {
      std::cout << "done:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
   });
```

**UPDATE 2**: The following, adding a launch policy `launch::deferred`, will also work:

```
   foo.start().then(boost::launch::deferred, [](boost::future<int> f) {
      std::cout << "done:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
   });
```

and this also:

```
   boost::future<int> start() {
      boost::future<int> f = p.get_future();
      f.set_deferred();
      return f;
   }
```

Comment: Hah. I was just answering. Your variable `f2` extends the lifetime of the future until /after/ the promise has been made ready. This is a change. So, yes, `f2` is being implicitely used (if only for the destructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, your composed future is not kept around. In fact, it is a temporary and it gets destructed as soon as the statement (with `.then()`) ends.

Fix it:

```
int main () {
    Foo foo;

    auto f1 = foo.start();
    auto f2 = f1.then([](boost::future<int> f) {
        std::cout << "done:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
    });

    foo.finish();
    f2.get();
}
```

Now it prints

```
done:
23
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da86563c2faba8a0)**

If you move the `f2.get()` before the `foo.finish()` it will dead lock again.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. However, in the meantime I found out about "launch policies". Since I don't need `f2` actually (if I would, then I needed to keep it around), the use of launch policy seems more appropriate? Please see "UPDATE 2" in Q ..

Comment: If you mean, there was a lack of thread concurrrency, then yes, this explained the deadlock. However, `deferred` just mean that the task is not "eagerly" scheduled, the overriding change would be running it on a thread. Instead, I'd expect you to **[use `async` to introduce threads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f6aae169fdd2e8e)**. Just using the `deferred` flag only makes doubly sure that none of your tasks ever get triggered, since you do not wait on the second future.

Comment: FWIW, I don't want to use threads at all. I want to have asynchronous control flow on a single (main) thread. As in JavaScript promises or Twisted Deferreds. I am still learning this stuff in C++ land ..

Comment: @oberstet May I heartily recommend Boost Asio for this? Especially look at coroutines, but in general if you're look for reactor-style concurrency (on a single thread or many) - Boost Asio is your next stop

Comment: @oberstet I just wrote a simple http sample client with Boost Asio here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22605624/85371 perhaps you'll recognize the reactor style. It's not a very compelling example of asynchrony, but it does cancel on Eccleston of a deadline timer :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I've been working with Asio before, but in old-school callback style, not co-routines. Wasn't aware Asio does co-routines these days. Neat! I prefer continuation style however for the project at hand .. this is what I got working: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnCpp/blob/master/test/test7.cpp#L40 - this includes a poor-man's event loop under the hood for talking WAMP (a RPC+PubSub protocol) over stdio.

Comment: Oh good. Seems like you have things under control then. Cheers

Comment: Yep, mostly;) Thanks again for helping out!